# Transform a point in a coordinate system to another by using two 3D points

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations, transformation

I am facing a problem with the transformation from one coordinate system to another coordinate system.
I have 2 coordinate systems and one 3D point in each coordinate system. For example in **Coordinate System A**, I have a 3D point **(14, 23, 65 )** and if I transform it to **Coordinate System B**, that 3D point will be **(-1, 2, 5)**. So whenever I have another 3D point in **Coordinate System A**, I want to transform it to **Coordinate System B**. I have tried to check on some affine transformation but I still can not understand it well. Is there any solution to this?

Thank you

Comment: If your coordinate systems are rotated, one point is not enough to find transformation formula. In 3d case you need at least 3 points. If only translations are involved, single point  should he fine to find the formula.

Comment: Thank you @Tomek but if I have 3 or more points, what formula should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 linearly-independant points $p^1$, $p^2$ and $p^3$ corresponding to points  $q^1$, $q^2$ and $q^3$. You need to solve for the unknown matrix in the following system:

$\begin{bmatrix}
q^1_x&q^2_x&q^3_x\\
q^1_y&q^2_y&q^3_y\\
q^1_z&q^2_z&q^3_z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a&d&g\\
b&e&h\\
c&f&i
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
p^1_x&p^2_x&p^3_x\\
p^1_y&p^2_y&p^3_y\\
p^1_z&p^2_z&p^3_z\\
\end{bmatrix}$

You have 9 unknowns and 9 equations.

Comment: And if I found the matrix a,d,g,b,e,h,c,f,i. Is it the rotation matrix or any coefficient to find another new coordinate?

Comment: The two coordinate systems might differ by (a combination of) rotation, scaling, shearing and reflection.